# Does it make any sense to use multiple ports in your TCP socket-based software

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I'm writing some software in python which has 2 major modules:

1. File processing module, which takes files one by one from a list of files in a folder and does some calculations.
2. File transfer module, which is responsible for accepting files via TCP sockets from various sources and saving them on the HDDs (from a few connections to many at once).

I need the first module to respond to me and some other maintainers on the current status of the queue + general statistics + the capability of sending commands to it while it's working.

It doesn't really matter for me whether to run 2 separate ports or a single one, because I'm initializing the entire system from a single file, using shared functions (for handshakes and so on), etc...

So, is there any advantage in having individual port numbers assigned to these 2 modules?

If this is the wrong place to ask this I would be very thankful if someone could point to the right one.

Comment: if it makes the programming easier, that's the advantage

Comment: Running everything on a single port requires more work to differentiate which packets belong to which operation, unless you have a handshake that specifies that kind of info up front.  Whereas using separate ports may simplify the traffic for each operation.